# in place updates causes forwarded records

Tags: sql-server, update, heap

I am well aware what a forwarded record within a heap is. Since I want to keep forwarded records at 0, we decided to update only on columns that could not be extended.

Recently on my system I encountered forwarded records.
Table design is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (
 HashValue BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
 LoadTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
 LoadEndTime DATETIME NULL,
[other columns that never get updates]
) WITH(DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE);
```

The insert statements ALWAYS bring `HashValue` AND `LoadTime`. I checked the query logs.
I insert a value of '9999-12-31'.

Now system performs an update on `LoadTime` like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, COALESCE(LEAD(LoadTime) OVER(PARTITION BY HashValue ORDER BY LoadTime) ,'9999-12-31') as EndTimeStamp
)
UPDATE CTE SET LoadEndTime = EndTimeStamp;
```

Since the `LoadEndTime` column is always filled, there should be no extension of that column within the row when the update is executed. It should be an in place update. Still I get forwarded records always after that process... It doesn't make sense to me.

Insert Statement is like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.test (HashValue, LoadTime,LoadEndTime)
SELECT HASHBYTES(...), GETDATE(), '1900-01-01'
```

So there is already a dummy value. Even with compression the fixed and variable representation of datetime '1900-01-01 00:00:00' should be 8 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to compression.

Compressed table has no more `FixedVar` row format, so even if you use fixed-length columns they aren't stored in Fixedvar way, no more fixed space reserved for (even `NULL`) values.

When you use page compression, frist ROW COMPRESSION is applied.
And here what we have:[Row Compression Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/row-compression-implementation)

> It stores fixed character strings by using variable-length format by
>   not storing the blank characters. Note
>
> NULL and 0 values across all data types are optimized and take no
>   bytes.

Here is my repro where I use dbo.Nums, table of 1000000 natural numbers, to fill my two tables: `dbo.test_comp` with page compression enabled and `dbo.test_no_comp` with no compression:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test_comp (
 id int,
 LoadTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
 LoadEndTime DATETIME NULL,
filler char(200) default 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewyyyyyyyykshdgfgsklghkfdjglfdvlaepeoèrehjblgjbltdjgljreglrelgretgregrtegregreqw'
) 
WITH(DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE);

insert into dbo.test_comp(id,  LoadTime)
select n, getdate()
from dbo.nums;

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS table_name, forwarded_record_count, avg_fragmentation_in_percent, page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.test_comp'), DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'DETAILED');

--table_name    forwarded_record_count  avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
--test_comp 0   11,7117117117117    18519

UPDATE dbo.test_comp SET LoadEndTime = LoadTime;

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS table_name, forwarded_record_count, avg_fragmentation_in_percent, page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.test_comp'), DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'DETAILED');

--table_name    forwarded_record_count  avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
--test_comp 54949   11,1783696529459    19688


CREATE TABLE dbo.test_no_comp (
 id int,
 LoadTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
 LoadEndTime DATETIME NULL,
filler char(200) default 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewyyyyyyyykshdgfgsklghkfdjglfdvlaepeoèrehjblgjbltdjgljreglrelgretgregrtegregreqw'
) 

insert into dbo.test_no_comp(id,  LoadTime)
select n, getdate()
from dbo.nums;

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS table_name, forwarded_record_count, avg_fragmentation_in_percent, page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.test_no_comp'), DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'DETAILED');

--table_name    forwarded_record_count  avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
--test_no_comp  0   6,22905027932961    28572

UPDATE dbo.test_no_comp SET LoadEndTime = LoadTime;

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS table_name, forwarded_record_count, avg_fragmentation_in_percent, page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.test_no_comp'), DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'DETAILED');

--table_name    forwarded_record_count  avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
--test_no_comp  0   6,22905027932961    28572
```

**UPDATE**

> Even with compression the fixed and variable representation of
>   datetime '1900-01-01 00:00:00' should be 8 bytes

This is completely untrue, because you use `PAGE` compression that creates a dictionary and substitute repeating values:

> **Dictionary compression**
>
> After prefix compression is applied to every
>   column individually, the second phase of page compression looks at
>   all values on the page to find duplicates in any column of any row,
>   even if they have  been encoded to reflect prefix usage. The
>   process of  detecting duplicate values is data type–agnostic, so
>   values in completely different columns could  be the same in their
>   binary representation. For example, a 1-byte character is represented
>   in hex as  0x54, and it would be seen as a duplicate of the 1-byte
>   integer 84, which is also represented in hex  as 0x54. The dictionary
>   is stored as a set of symbols, each of which corresponds to a
>   duplicated value  on the data page. After the symbols and data values
>   are determined, each occurrence of one of the  duplicated values is
>   replaced by the symbol. SQL Server recognizes that the value actually
>   stored in  the column is a symbol and not a data value by examining
>   the encoding in the CD array. Values which  have been replaced by
>   symbols have a CD array value of 0xc.

But I wanted point out another thing.
Did you test if your PAGE compression make sense at all in your case?
You have a heap and it's not static, i.e. you update it.

> **Compression of heap pages**
>
> **Pages in a heap are checked for possible compression only during 
>   rebuild** and shrink operations. Also, if you drop a clustered index on
>   a table so that it becomes a heap, SQL Server runs compression
>   analysis on any full pages. To make sure that the RowID values stay
>   the same, heaps aren’t recompressed during typical data modification
>   operations. Although the Page-ModCount value is maintained, SQL Server
>   never tries to recompress a page based on the PageMod-Count value

So in your case even if you can achieve compression on INSERT (only if you use bulk insert with `tablock`), any update will only destroy your compression.

Look at my new test.

I realized that in my first test when i did INSERT without tablock, only row compression was applied, I inserted 1000000 rows and I get 19688 pages.
Now I insert with tablock into the same table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test_comp (
 id int,
 LoadTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
 LoadEndTime DATETIME not NULL,
filler char(200) default 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmnbvcxzlkjhgfdsapoiuytrewyyyyyyyykshdgfgsklghkfdjglfdvlaepeoèrehjblgjbltdjgljreglrelgretgregrtegregreqw'
) 
WITH(DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE);

insert into dbo.test_comp with(tablock) (id,  LoadTime, LoadEndTime)
select n, getdate(), getdate()
from dbo.nums;

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS table_name, forwarded_record_count, avg_fragmentation_in_percent, page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.test_comp'), DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'DETAILED');

--table_name    forwarded_record_count  avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
--test_comp 0   0   1387
```

Now I have only 1387 pages.
1387 vs 19688 only because in first case page compression, even if defined, was not applied since my INSERT was without **tablock**

And now I update my nice compressed table:

```
UPDATE dbo.test_comp SET LoadEndTime = getdate();

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS table_name, forwarded_record_count, avg_fragmentation_in_percent, page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.test_comp'), DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'DETAILED');

--table_name    forwarded_record_count  avg_fragmentation_in_percent    page_count
--test_comp 990247  8,43971631205674    22442
```

Wow, after update I have 22422 pages vs 1387 original pages!

After this test I really NEVER will use page compression on a heap that is not static. The final table size is not much less compared with its non-compressed analog but as a bonus I have 990247 forwarded records out of 1000000

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Worth noting about heaps and compression:

> From [Data Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression) in the product documentation:
>
> When a heap is configured for page-level compression, pages receive page-level compression only in the following ways:
>
> - Data is bulk imported with bulk optimizations enabled.
> - Data is inserted using `INSERT INTO ... WITH (TABLOCK)` syntax and the table does not have a nonclustered index.
> - A table is rebuilt by executing the `ALTER TABLE ... REBUILD` statement with the `PAGE` compression option.

Your `UPDATE` therefore cannot perform an in-place update, with the consequences noted.

---

As a workaround, if you use date-based partitioning, you can leave the most recent partition uncompressed. Also Clustered columnstore tables do something similar, with initial inserts going to a row store, and later being compressed into Column segments.